# How to override labels in treeview in Simplicite?

Tags: java, rhino

On Simplicite treeviews the default "short label" of business objects' records is the concatenation of all business keys, which is not always ideal (typically when there are many fields in this business key).

Is there a way to override this default label ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a business hook called `getUserKeyLabel` that can be used to override the default label.

To restrict this only to the treeview usage you can write it like this:

```
MyBusinessObject.getUserKeyLabel = function(row) {
    // Override the record label on treeview
    if (this.isTreeviewInstance())
        return row[this.getFieldIndex("myFirstField")] + " - " + row[this.getFieldIndex("mySecondField");
}
```